# Example of this prototype OOP code in FP style

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

So. I'm reading a lot of articles regarding Functional Programming and I'm finding a lot of related issues with all of them... They are all talk and no play. They all talk about Functional Programming but noone actual *shows* an example and the ones who do show examples, show completely different examples than that of the OOP they show, so it is hard to relate between the two. The one thing that is hard to grasp is *state* in functional programming. So, for the sake of it, could someone answer this post and write a functional programming approach to the below OOP style code.

`person.json`:

```
{
    "firstname": "Karl",
    "surname": "Morrison"
}
```

`person.js`:

```
// Module code

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

function Person(filePath) {
    const person = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, filePath)));
    this.firstname = person.firstname;
    this.surname = person.surname;
    this.salary = 0;
}

Person.prototype.getPerson = function() {
    return {
        firstname: this.firstname,
        surname: this.surname,
        salary: this.salary
    }
}

Person.prototype.increaseSalary = function(amount) {
    this.salary += amount;
}

Person.prototype.increaseSalary = function(amount) {
    this.salary += amount;
}

Person.prototype.getYearlySalary = function() {
    return this.salary * 12;
}


// Application code

const people = [];

const personOne = new Person('./person_one.json');
console.log(personOne.getPerson()); // { firstname: 'Karl', surname: 'Morrison', salary: 0 }
personOne.increaseSalary(1000);
console.log(personOne.getPerson()); // { firstname: 'Karl', surname: 'Morrison', salary: 1000 }
console.log(personOne.getYearlySalary()); // 12000

people.push(personOne);

const personTwo = new Person('./person_two.json');
console.log(personTwo.getPerson()); // { firstname: 'Eric', surname: 'McDood', salary: 0 }
personTwo.increaseSalary(100);
console.log(personTwo.getPerson()); // { firstname: 'Eric', surname: 'McDood', salary: 100 }
console.log(personTwo.getYearlySalary()); // 1200

people.push(personTwo);

// API endpoint - This would be an example of returning the state of the people to whoever made the request. State needs to be kept.

function APIGetPeopleCallback() {
    return people;
}

function APIAddPersonCallback(filePath) {
    people.push(new Person(filePath));
}
```

Comment: `const increaseSalary = (p, amount) => ({ ...p, salary: p.salary + amount });`

Comment: @JonasWilms You are acting like all the blogs now.

Comment: @KarlMorrison the flip side of that (and I'm not trying to be flippant) is that your ~50 LoC is an awful lot of boilerplate for what should be a one-liner....

Comment: `person = increaseSalary(person)`

Comment: @JaredSmith It is an *example*. It's not production code! Imagine making a very complex OOP object where prototype functions and mutation of instance variables are in play.

Comment: @KarlMorrison that makes it *worse*, not better! How big would it be when you added validation and error handling? At the end of the day you're just updating a single number value.

Comment: @JaredSmith Did you read my post at all or did you just skip to the code?

Comment: @JaredSmith This is how OOP code is written. For people with OOP backgrounds it's hard for them to make the jump to FP *due to the lack of examples*.

Comment: @JonasWilms Indeed that is how it is done for a pure function call, again, like all of the blogs already show. But how would state management work for an API application where a state has to be managed. Think about the *bigger* picture. I have a file read here, which can never be pure. This is why I'd like an example *of the whole code*.

Comment: This is too broad a question. State is hold in the function call stack in FP - it is that easy. So instead of reassigning a value to a variable you call a function with the new value as an argument. In order to avoid mutaions you use persistent data types.

Comment: @bob no it is not. Where's the state stored if the callstack is empty?

Comment: @JonasWilms This is a very good question. For others: With asynchronous computations the original call stack is lost. So where is the state then? Well, the asynchronous effect is modeled through continuation and the corresponding monad in FP. Continuations are lazily evaluated, that is you build up a huge deferred function call tree when composing them. This tree is evaluated only when you actually run the continuiation. Voilá, there is the call stack again, there is the state.

Comment: @bob oh, that could actually be replicated in JS with generator functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here you go:

```
 ((people, loadPerson, increaseSalary) => (
     people(it => [...it, increaseSalary(loadPerson('./person_one.json'), 1000))]),
     people(it => [...it, increaseSalary(loadPerson('./person_two.json'), 100))]),
     { getPeople: () => people(), addPerson: (path) => people(it => [...it, loadPerson(path)]) }
 ))(
   (s => e => s = e ? e(s) : s)([]),
   file => JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, file))),
   (p, amount) => ({ ...p, salary: p.salary + amount })
 )
```

Takeaways:

"purely functional code" in an asynchronous world is complicated.

Purely functional code in a multiparadigm language is impossible, as all APIs impose different paradigms.

Comment: Damn you're getting close now! Lacks the file read(your loadPerson function), people variable, increaseSalary function and two API function callbacks!

Comment: @karl it does read files? Also, the two API functions is what the whole thing evaluates to.

Comment: Ok true. So I see here mutation going on with the people.push, could you explain a little further on why you didn't create a map and return a new array and set that array somewhere.

Comment: Oh indeed, this could even get a bit more functional (but honestly, less *functioning*)

Comment: My post here on SO was so that other beginners could find it and understand the differences. So I'd actually prefer it if it was faf (functional as ****). So you are saying by not making this as pure/functional as possible the trade off would be you said less functioning? What do you mean by this?

Comment: `There is no such thing as "purely functional code" in an asynchronous world.`, this is EXACTLY what blogs do not talk about. Blogs ALWAYS talk only about how everything should be pure.

Comment: @karl honestly, would you ship that code? Probably not  . "functional programming" means you have ideas such as *immutability* and *purity* in mind, but not every piece of your code will/should/can strictly follow it.

Comment: Probably because most bloggers don't know what they are talking about.

Comment: I couldn't be more in agreeance. I am satisfied with your answer as it will get most people reading this on their merry way.

Comment: What do you mean by 'there is no such thing as "purely functional code" in an asynchronous world'? Of course there is. You build a pure abstraction of the computation and then run it. For example, IO actions in Haskell are purely functional. It's only when you run the IO actions that they actually produce side effects. It's the difference between `console.log("Hello World!")`, i.e. a computation, and `() => console.log("Hello World!")`, i.e. a description of a computation.

Comment: @aadit and were is the reference to your function kept until the async action triggers?

Comment: In memory, like everything else on a computer.

Comment: _There is no such thing as "purely functional code" in an asynchronous world._ - Even promises would be purely functional if it weren't for the strict evaluation of the promise constructor. You can't make your entire program purely functional, but you can defer impurity to the edge of your program so that large parts remain purely functional.

Comment: @AaditMShah I can't help but feel this has turned into something of a semantic debate about the meaning of the term "purely functional code" rather than a real point of disagreement. I could be wrong about that.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with this request

> functional programming approach to the below OOP style code

1. There's absolutely nothing OOP about the code you posted. You could have a module-level object with salary hashed by name or some other thing and expose getters and setters to manipulate it. This is plain procedural code with a **very** thin coat of OO paint. I get that it's an example and is supposed to be simplified, but it actually gets right to the heart of the problem...
2. Paradigms when used correctly are not line-by-line (or even module-by-module!) translatable from one to the other. Think about a *real* OO design for some problem. You can use one of the classics like the parking garage or monopoly or some problem you've actually solved in an app. Most of your classes probably have only the most tenuous connections to physical entities, and instead are related to things like state change invariant enforcement (i.e. validation) and policy. Think about the way the interaction between instances is mediated, with all the layers of indirection and the Law of Demeter and yada. Now imagine someone comes to you with a procedural implementation of a solution and says "how do I translate this to OOP?".

You can't. I mean, sure, you can create an example like the one you posted which is really still procedural, but how would you even begin to explain how to do an actual OO solution? You'd have to start at the very beginning and work your way up from first principles. It's not a different *style* of *coding*, it's a completely different way of *modeling problems*. For another example, think about the difference between how things are modeled in most programming languages vs. say, relational tables in a database.

And that's why the blogs are annoying you, they're trying to explain things (and I realize I'm painting with a broad brush here) from the first principles, the way it *has* to be done, when you seem want the TL;DR. I freely admit it doesn't help that those explanations are mixed with a sales pitch, but que cirra.

Comment: *"This is plain procedural code with a very thin coat of OO paint"*, that is the whole point... Well since you can't abstract it enough (I get the vibe of **curse of knowledge** from you) I guess you won't be able to answer my question properly. I don't see any FP code, so I will no be accepting this.

Comment: @KarlMorrison yes, *it is the whole point*: you can write procedural in any language. But it isn't FP any more that your example is OO. See Jonas Wilm's examples for proof.

Comment: @KarlMorrison also, you may be right about the curse of knowledge thing. I can think of several examples of things that seemed completely obtuse to me when I didn't understand them (closures, monads, promises in JS), and completely obvious once the lightbulb clicked.

Comment: To be honest my code does three things. 1) Starts up and loads from two files. 2) Can take an asynchronous request for all of the people 3) Can take an asynchronous request to add a person. - I just happened to use object instances with mutable instance variables for my example. What most OOP people can't wrap their head around is where the returned state objects should be kept (from prure functions in FP) when updated and how that updated object should be fetched (for example by an API request). In OOP it's very simple, you keep the state in the object instance.

Comment: @KarlMorrison even in OOP it's not that simple (although I'm not sure how much of what I'm about to nitpick came from you trying to keep a reasonably short example). For instance, your code (from my perspective) does the following: 1. reads a file 2. parses the contents into a data structure. 3. updates the resulting data 4. exposes a data structure of the data structures from 2. So why are you tangling 3 of those separate concerns in a single constructor? You could (should?) have a class that takes a filepath and returns a file handle, a class that takes a file handle and reads the data out..

Comment: ...of it, a class that validates that data before passing it to the actual business entity constructor (Person in this example), a class that keeps tabs on (mediates access to) a list of Persons, etc. etc. Or you could represent it as a composition of functions: `Person(validatePersonData(parsePersonFile(readPersonFile(path))));`

Comment: ...And you might see that and say: "what if something from the middle of the chain throws?" and holy carp now we've got to talk about Either and monads and now the rabbit hole is a million miles deep. It's easier for the teacher and the student to start at the bottom and work up.

Comment: @JaredSmith, again, it's just an example! A beginner will see the code and understand it! Regarding the rabbit hole I agree with you fully. I've seen functional code that was 12 calls deep (not all at once, but split over 8 files).

Comment: @KarlMorrison yup yup. Also graphs of object calls every bit that deep. Sometimes the problem domain simply requires that level of complexity. Sometimes it doesn't. But taking a different tack with it: abstractions are built on abstractions are built on...you get it. You can't even talk about something as fundamental to getting stuff done as handling exceptions without getting into 2 or 3 completely new concepts, which is why blogs are long on trivial examples and short on actually useful ones. It's the same with OOP. How many (crappy) OOP tutorials have you seen where they yammer on about...

Comment: ...how OOP objects "model the real world"? My OOP objects usually *have nothing to do with physical ones in the real world*. No OOP programmer programs that way, yet it's all tutorials want to talk about. 'Cat' inherits from 'Animal' which has a virtual method 'speak' blah blah blah. As soon as you want to do something non-trivial though you've got AbstractProxyPolicyFactoryManager objects and now the rabbit hole is a million miles deep.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure you're going to get the answer you're looking for. It's kind of like saying, "could somebody please take this classical tune and rewrite it as a blues song, with clear rules that show how to do it." You'd never get to the bottom of it. In fact (as you see already), many would say, "that's not a classical song so your request is misguided."

So if I may, I'd submit this as a better place to start: "please give me a PRACTICAL example."

To that end, three of the most practical things I ever heard when I was going through this was:

"OOP's notions of types are fine grained. Functional's notion of types are course grained."

"OOP is more types with less methods. Functional is less types with more methods."

"OOP creates deeper, more brittle hierarchies. Functional creates shallower, often flat, structures."

None of these are meant to be absolute edicts, they are meant to differentiate the thinking, which IMHO is the most important thing to understand about Functional and OOP (notice I do not say "vs.").

Consider what you've got up there: you create a Person type, and it has some methods that are specific to processing THAT type.

So if you need "BigPerson", what will you do? You'll probably extend Person. Makes sense; hierarchy, reuse, etc. You'll add BigPerson methods, or, you'll have to implement IPerson in both Person and BigPerson so that you can alter the behaviors on a type-by-type basis (or just override the functions in the prototype), or some such. More types, more specific, deeper hierarchy.

Now, consider a list to hold such objects. How would you type it? Person (or IPerson)? Might not be specific enough for BigPerson. So you'd type it as BigPerson (or, create IBigPerson and use that). Many might even create BigPersonList implements IBigPersonList (I see this ALL the time and it drives me nutz...you end up with a different list type for every component that displays a list). And then let's say you want a list as an array, then a list as a Set. IBigPersonArray, IBigPersonSet? Or implement other types and interfaces that abstract List and Set, and implement those in BigPerson (BigPersonList extends PersonList implements IArrayList...)

Don't laugh, I've seen these patterns so many times in the wild anybody saying "no employed professional would do that" is simply wrong. (In fact I might actually say that in my experience, the more academic training a programmer has, the more likely they are to do it.)

A functional programmer might say: I'm not going to go through all that. I need a list; all lists are fundamentally the same, they are a collection of objects. The difference in all that typing and interface business is the behavior to process the types you give it.

So I will create a list, with a function that accepts a function, which tells the list how to process the types; the list itself will not contain anything other than the most rudimentary behavior to stuff objects into an array (in fact, I could actually let the user determine what top-level data structure to use, they can just pass it in along with the function). It'll also have an arg, "type", so that you can ask "what type of list is this." And, if they need to use the same processing logic somewhere else, they can simply grab the function that this "type" of list uses, and do whatever they want with it somewhere else. I can even let them pass in the logic to iterate it.

So one of my own notions of functional and OOP; OOP sets the instructions in stone. If the dev wants different instructions, they extend/override/etc. Functional allows the developer to provide those instructions, so that you don't need another static type.

Taken to the extreme, types disappear. Everything is just dynamically provided instructions to "higher order" functionality. What's important is top-level functionality that accepts instructions on how to extend its capability. A "list" can hold anything. It doesn't need to be typed, and it doesn't need to care about the type it holds, because the developer told it how to handle it (with instructions-as-functions). As long as another developer can inspect enough info about it to understand what it holds and how it holds/provides it (sometimes called "duck typing", if it looks like a duck and acts like a duck, it's practical to assume it's a duck, I don't need the class->order->species of it), you're good.

The strengths and weaknesses come to mind pretty quickly. They are debated endlessly. Personally, I think the best practice is a smart combination of both.

So in your example, I wouldn't rewrite Person. But in more abstract things that would handle things like Person, that's where I may approach more functionally.

Hope that helps. It'll probably cost me some rep.

Comment: "classical tune and rewrite it as a blues song", this is actually very possible in the real-world and does happen. It's like rock covers of pop songs, and would be the same in this as well.
"Functional creates shallower, even flat, structures.", I agree!

I must admit, one of the more clear examples on the web in text! Would of been great if this example was written in code for both OOP and Functional.

Comment: Regarding my code does the following:  1) Starts up and loads from two files. 2) Can take an asynchronous request for all of the people 3) Can take an asynchronous request to add a person. Which would be possible in FP. So I'm sorry but I do not agree with that my example cannot be written in FP as it can.

Nonetheless a very good answer! (It gave you some rep by my standards ;))

Comment: @Karl you're taking this much too literally. However, I'll point out that I'm an academically trained musician playing for longer than many people on SO have been alive, and that if you were to pose that task to ten musicians, some classically trained, some blues pros, and the rest somewhere in between, you'd get ten different songs, and they'll all disagree on various points of the conversion. The only thing you could probably get consensus on is the general quality of the outcome.

Comment: Interestingly, I kind of think of it in a way as Bach vs. Mozart. "Better" is sort of meaningless. But studying both makes you a better musician. Possibly a more interesting way to consider it would be, "what kind of blues would Bach write, how would it be different than Mozart's?" And if they were to both rewrite the same song, no doubt it would be different (which is my point to @Karl).

Comment: I am also a musician ;) and I don't recognize `academically trained` as a *higher status* than those that aren't. Some of the most successful musicians have no academic training (I could go on for ages about this but yes, we shall not go there hah!).

Regarding the anology I understand you and I agree, the general quality of outcome would differ absolutely. I would like to point out this question wasn't really for me, but for others struggling with getting into FP. Your answer will help!

Comment: Your latest post: Indeed!

Comment: My point is not about status (please let's not get into the "Hendrix didn't have theory" debate). It's about having studied the "rules". And I can say that in my training I have never seen anybody state or read any book that asserts, "this is exactly how you rewrite a classical song into a blues song."